# Stuck in Facebook login using ionic and ngCordovaOauth

Tags: ios, cordova

I have been struggling with this for 2 or more days.
It just do not work. I get stuck on the "cannot GET /callback" screen, no matter what.

I am trying Facebook login.

My setup:

- Site URL: http://localhost/callback
- Mobile Site URL: http://localhost/callback
- Ionic: 1.4.1
- I ran:

  ```
  cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
  cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
  ```
- At my app.js:

  ```
  angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova','starter.controllers', 'starter.services','app-constants','ui.utils.masks.br.phone'])
  ```

  At my login-service.js:

  ```
  angular.module('starter.services').service('LoginService', function($http, apiEndPoint, $location, $cordovaOauth)
  ```

  ....

  ```
  facebookLogin: function() {
  return $cordovaOauth.facebook(appID, ["email", "read_stream", "user_website", "user_location", "user_relationships"]).then(function(result) {

      accessToken = result.access_token;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
      return accessToken
  }, function(error) {
      alert("There was a problem signing in!  See the console for logs");
      alert(error);
      console.log(error);
  });
  },
  ```

At config.xml:

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

Running both on iOS emulator and iOS real device. Emulation both via ionic emulate ios and via Xcode.

I have already reinstalled everything, even Nodejs.

I get this:
[image: error using iOS emulator]

I believe that it is related to a ng-cordova-oauth bug: https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/issues/43

I posted there too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I solved!! The problem is not the ngCordovaOauth.
The problem was that Facebook was returning an error code instead of the access_token.

So the solution was changing:

```
facebookLogin: function() {
   return $cordovaOauth.facebook(appID, ["email", "read_stream", "user_website", "user_location", "user_relationships"]).then(function(result) {
```

to this:

```
facebookLogin: function() {
   return $cordovaOauth.facebook(appID, ["email"]).then(function(result) {
```